# Javascript - validar formulario se este for clickado

Tags: javascript, html

Dentro de um `<form>` tenho dois formularios mas um não é de preenchimento obrigatorio, apenas se a pessoa quiser introduzir um novo endereço. o problema que esta acontecer é que independente de a pessoa fazer click na checkbox, a validação em javascript exige que o usuario preencha os dados da checkbox mesmo a checkbox não sendo clickada. Ha alguma maneira de contornar isto com javascript?

HTML código:

```
<form name="form" action="orders.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return Validatedatacheckout()" >
<table id="address" style="display:none">
    <tr>
    <td> 
    Door number:<input type="text" placeholder="doornumber" name="doornumber" value=""  id="doornumber">
    Road:<input type="text" placeholder="road" name="road" value=""  id ="road">
    Country:<input type="text" placeholder="country" name="country" value="" id="country">
    Post Code:<input type="text" placeholder="postcode" name="postcode"  value=""  id="postcode"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<label><input name ="differentAddress" id="differentAddress" type='checkbox'>Use a different home address</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h5>Please enter your bank details.</h5>
<div class="form-container">
    <span class="input-label">First Name:</span><input type="text"  placeholder="First name" name="firstName"> <br>
    <span class="input-label">Last Name:</span><input type="text" name="lastName"  placeholder="Last Name"> <br>
    <span class="input-label">Account Number:</span><input type="text" name="accountnumber"  placeholder="account number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)"> <br>
    <span class="input-label">Security Number:</span><input type="text" name="securitynumber"  placeholder="security number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)">
</div>
    <br>
    <br>
<input id="checksub" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function Validatedatacheckout(){
    var doornumber = document.form.doornumber;
    var road= document.form.road;
    var postcode = document.form.postcode;
    var country = document.form.country;
    var accountnumber = document.form.accountnumber;
    var securitynumber = document.form.securitynumber;

    if (doornumber.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a door number.");
        doornumber.focus();
        return false;
    }
       if (road.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a road name.");
        road.focus();
        return false;
    } 

    if (postcode.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a post code.");
        postcode.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (country.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a country.");
        country.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (accountnumber.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter an account number.");
        accountnumber.focus();
        return false;
    }
     if (securitynumber.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a security number.");
        securitynumber.focus();
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: No caso, a primeira parte do formulário que não será obrigatória, apenas se o usuário selecionar a opção `differentAddress`? Se sim, basta verificar os valores dos campos apenas se um valor do `checkbox` for verdadeiro (fazer um `if`).

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você deseja verificar os campos `doornumber`, `road`, `postcode` e `country` apenas se `differentAddress` estiver selecionado, você pode fazer algo como:

```js
// Pega o elemento checkbox:
var differentAddress = document.getElementById("differentAddress");

// Pega o elemento que será exibido quando o checkbox for marcado:
var address = document.getElementById("address");

// Exibe ou oculta a parte do formulário quando o checkbox estiver marcado:
differentAddress.onchange = function(event) {
  if (differentAddress.checked) {
    address.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    address.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

function Validatedatacheckout() {
  var doornumber = document.form.doornumber;
  var road = document.form.road;
  var postcode = document.form.postcode;
  var country = document.form.country;
  var accountnumber = document.form.accountnumber;
  var securitynumber = document.form.securitynumber;

  // Verifica se o checkbox está marcado:
  if (differentAddress.checked) {
    if (doornumber.value == "") {
      window.alert("Please enter a door number.");
      doornumber.focus();
      return false;
    }
    
    if (road.value == "") {
      window.alert("Please enter a road name.");
      road.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (postcode.value == "") {
      window.alert("Please enter a post code.");
      postcode.focus();
      return false;
    }
    
    if (country.value == "") {
      window.alert("Please enter a country.");
      country.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (accountnumber.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please enter an account number.");
    accountnumber.focus();
    return false;
  }
  
  if (securitynumber.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please enter a security number.");
    securitynumber.focus();
    return false;
  }
  
  alert("Tudo ok");
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="orders.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return Validatedatacheckout()">
  <table id="address" style="display:none">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Door number:<input type="text" placeholder="doornumber" name="doornumber" value="" id="doornumber"> Road:
        <input type="text" placeholder="road" name="road" value="" id="road"> Country:
        <input type="text" placeholder="country" name="country" value="" id="country"> Post Code:<input type="text" placeholder="postcode" name="postcode" value="" id="postcode"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <label><input name ="differentAddress" id="differentAddress" type='checkbox'>Use a different home address</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h5>Please enter your bank details.</h5>
  <div class="form-container">
    <span class="input-label">First Name:</span><input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstName"> <br>
    <span class="input-label">Last Name:</span><input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"> <br>
    <span class="input-label">Account Number:</span><input type="text" name="accountnumber" placeholder="account number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)"> <br>
    <span class="input-label">Security Number:</span><input type="text" name="securitynumber" placeholder="security number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="checksub" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

> Adicionei um código para exibir ou ocultar a parte do formulário conforme o checkbox for marcado ou não. Não sei se você faz isso em outra parte do código, mas se sim, pode desconsiderar essa parte da resposta e o que te interessa possivelmente é somente o `if` adicionado na função `Validatedatacheckout`.

Comment: oi eu ja tenho essa parte no meu codigo que esconde o formulario. entao tentei seu codigo a parte do endereço esta funcionado mas a parte de colocar o numero da conta etc nao mostra nenhum alerta e deixa eu submeter mesmo os campos estando vazios